# Rails resetting session after login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication

In my Rails 4 App Im trying to authentificate a User which works but after the following redirect the session is reset and as a consequence of that empty.

The `auth` action is pretty simple

```
  def auth
    logger.info "CALLING AUTH METHOD"
    user = User.auth(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password])
    logger.info "USER: #{user.inspect}"
    if user
      logger.info "AUTH SUCCESSFULL"
      session[:current_user_id] = user.id
      logger.info "SET USER ID: #{session[:user_id]}"
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      logger.info "AUTH FAILED"
      redirect_to "/users/login"
    end
  end
```

The log entry which looks like a sucessfull login:

```
Started POST "/users/auth" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-21 10:49:38 +0200
Processing by UsersController#auth as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wvc9GxeKprFPvZX0MqdtDQi0j+Yi3RZk92IeKGMhFyD/WeMzefVwPyNfnyadhs1qFBI4wupi6YQm5B+Lh1ZJqA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"User", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Anmelden"}
CALLING AUTH METHOD
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`name` = 'User' LIMIT 1
USER: #<User id: 2, name: "User", password_encrypted: "21553e1e2823d5cb5fc1ed4633146edfb13e1565447026c2b6...", password_salt: "\\]=WA2ZIW^bOH]==@[`;JM?KMF``8M7K", role: "PARTICIPANT", loginable_type: "Laboratory", loginable_id: 3, created_at: "2015-07-20 13:51:50", updated_at: "2015-07-20 13:51:55">
AUTH SUCCESSFULL
SET USER ID: 2
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 212ms (ActiveRecord: 184.5ms)
```

But after this the session is reset. But the `authenticity_token` is present. I also tried to skip the validation of the token by adding `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to the controller but it didn't help.

Comment: Where do you see that the session is reset? Can you show the auth method?

Comment: Not in the logfile. I saw it in the Packet Capture. The Server sent a `Set-Cookie`header which set a new session.

Comment: Where does the auth method come from? Is it custom? Can you show the code? Maybe your manual session setting is interfering with something inside your auth method...

Comment: I wrote it on my own but theres definitifly nothing wrong with that. The problem is that the session gets reset. The auth method works perfectly.

Comment: Also try to log the `session[:current_user_id]` from your root action.

Comment: I did that but later changed it from `user_id` to `current_user_id` but forgot to change it in the logger. It is placed correctly in that session that is later reset.